# How to copy searched rows , which are marked with blue label in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am using notepad++ there are some text whose occurence is one in a row,
when i searched and marked ,notepad++ search them with blue label highlighting
those rows,i want to copy those marked characters or rows.
Please suggest!

Comment: Your question is better suited for superuser.com.

Answer (score 17):

In `Notepad++` (v5.9.3) it's done like this:

```
"Search" -> "Bookmark" -> "Copy Bookmarked Lines"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are menu points in the "search" menu for this. There you can cut, copy, paste or delete Rows with labels. (Sorry I am using Notepad++ in German, I can't tell the exact names of the entries.)